# How make all the dependencies needed for android development offline

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, offline

I have an internet connection problem, and cannot download dependencies on demand, as a solution I thought to download them at another computer and take them to my computer. Is there any method to download all dependencies at once and use them offline?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but only if you download it once.

Setting -> Build, Execution, Development -> Gradle

And select offline work:

[image]

I hope this is what you need.

Happy coding